# How to write test case for document.body.classList.add/remove in React useEffect with jest & enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing

How do I write unit test for following?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("overflow_hidden");
    return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove("overflow_hidden");
    }
  }, []);
```